# Which is the best algorithm for finding the attacks from log file

Tags: linux

I m working on forensic analysis of web logs. I have generated the DoS attack dataset and i m having the attack dataset of log files (unlabeled dataset) taken from Dr. Anton Chuvakin. I need to look for access log, Error log file that generates various attacks such as XSS, XSRF, SQLI etc. I want to know which field is mainly for finding those attacks and let me know which is the suitable data mining/ Machine learning technique to attacks happened in log files. Please suggest me some idea  Please help me. I m struggling a lot to identify the suitable algorithm and if any materials pl send to me.

Comment: Your question is too broad.

Comment: Add more details to your question. Explain what you mean by 'learning algorithm' and 'attack'.

Comment: Thanks sir. I m working on forensic analysis of web logs. I have generated the DoS attack dataset and i m having the attack dataset of log files (unlabeled dataset) taken from Dr. Anton Chuvakin. I need to look for access log, Error log file that generates various attacks such as XSS, XSRF, SQLI etc. I want to know which field is mainly for finding those attacks and let me know which is the suitable data mining/ Machine learning technique to attacks happened in log files. Please suggest me some idea about this sir.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is quite broad. You need to specify which attacks are you monitoring, because they get logged into several logs ranging from the system logs you mentioned, to Apache logs, application server logs, etc.

A good way to start would be to make a list of every application/service your server is running, as well as open access points such as FTP or SSH and then monitoring each log. If you are able to simulate attacks then do it on a separate environment and look at how the system logs these events. You can then build upon that.

Another option is to install an intrusion detection system (IDS). This should be selected according to your needs and the size of the monitored system. Google "intrusion detection systems" and choose what you need.

Links that may interest you:

[Detecting Web Application attacks from log files](https://www.sans.org/reading-room/whitepapers/logging/detecting-attacks-web-applications-log-files-2074)

[How to tell if a Linux server is under DDOS attack](https://kb.hivelocity.net/how-to-check-if-your-linux-server-is-under-ddos-attack/)

[Checking SSH logs to prevent bruteforcing](http://www.developwebsites.net/check-linux-ssh-log/)

[Detecting attacks from Apache log files](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/117/can-i-detect-web-app-attacks-by-viewing-my-apache-log-file)

[Detection of XSS and SQLinjection attacks](http://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/detection-sql-injection-and-cross-site-scripting-attacks)

Comment: Thank You sir for your reply. I have generated DoS attack and i m having attack dataset of log files taken from Dr.Anton Chauvkin. we can find XSS, XSRF, SQLI, remote file inclusion attacks using Access log and Error log.I have to perform forensic analysis. I don't know which algorithm is the best for analyzing these attacks and what are the fields are needed to consider for finding theses attacks. Please suggest me sir.

Comment: Try to look up "decentralised bayesian algorithm". That's the only one which I can recall without searching on the web. Also a collegaue of mine just sent me a quite interesting paper on detecting attacks on web applications. Check out https://www.sans.org/reading-room/whitepapers/logging/detecting-attacks-web-applications-log-files-2074 I'm afraid I can't help you any further with a question of this scope. Maybe someone else will come with a better answer which will be of more help to you. Anyways, good luck!